# How can I run python2.7 specifically without specifying it at the command line?

Tags: python, linux, shell, alias

To give some background, I'm trying to "install" a python script so that users just run my install.py script and then they can run the main script (say, "awm") without doing any work themselves. This would look like:

> awm sync

for instance. Specifically, I didn't have to enter the full path to the python file "awm", and as a user I didn't have to go mess around with /etc/paths, /etc/profile, .bashrc, or whatever else, install.py did that for me.

My first go at this was adding "awm" to /etc/paths, which only works on Mac. So I branched, and added to /etc/profile to make it work on RHEL - the other target OS. Unfortunately, my companies' RHEL machines use Python 2.6, and "awm" requires Python 2.7. Aliases to the rescue...?

This brings me to the actual question - many of my teammates use different shells, for instance I use fish, some use zsh, others use bash, etc. Is there a way for me to add an alias without knowing the user's shell? Or am I SOL?

I am open to other solutions besides aliasing here, but this seemed like the most promising solution since aliases can manually specify the python version to use.

Comment: Why not install in a location in the default PATH such as `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Also, note that setuptools can automatically build a shim script that invokes whichever interpreter version you need.

Comment: Also, note that aliases *don't work at all* in a number of common situations. You can't start a shell alias from a noninteractive script. You can't start a shell alias with `find -exec`, or any other situation where no shell is in use (ie. `subprocess.Popen()` without `shell=True`). They're really best avoided in general; the number of times someone came to the freenode #bash channel with a problem about aliases during the years I was there and didn't get "don't use aliases" as their answer I can count on the fingers of one hand.

Comment: See http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html, and pay attention to the section on entry points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shebang for python 2.7 like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Assuming you’ve installed it in the PATH, you won’t even need .py at the end of the filename. Then you could invoke with:

```
awm sync
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I was already using a shebang, but with "python" instead of "python2.7"!